# Partially constrained vector and arrays in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, syntactic-sugar

Is there some way to define an alias, function or subtype in a package to define syntactic sugar around constrained vector declaration?

I often declare port and signals in VHDL as `std_logic_vector(N - 1 downto 0)`. I would like some syntactic sugar around this. something similar to this:

```
context work.common;

entity X is
    generic(
        byteSize : integer := 8
    );
    port(
        DataIn : in logic_bus(byteSize);
        DataOut : out logic_bus(byteSize)
    );
end entity;

architecture X_arch of X is
    signal DataSignal : logic_bus(byteSize);
begin
    DataOut <= DataSignal;
    DataSignal <= DataIn;
end architecture;
```

I would like to have this syntactic sugar defined all over my project, i.e., avoid defining a subtype in the architecture if possible. I'm very confused with the usage of `open`, `natural range <>`, the difference between `type` and `subtype`, and what kind of things functions can return.

## regarding constraints inference

I would like to stress that I'm looking for a way to abstract away the definition of similar vector constraints.

The proposal to leave my vector completely unconstrained, while a clever workaround, has strings attached to it that I would like to avoid :

- It is not compatible with type casting [see here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/614457/vhdl-how-to-assign-signal-of-different-types-to-port-map-with-constraint-infere).
- It doesn't communicate the relationship between ports (for instance it doesn't communicate that DataIn and DataOut are supposed to be the same size)
- It risks to allow badly sized bus designs to pass synthesis by mistake (accidental meaning)

For this reasons, my workplace coding style has banned unconstrained types in ports in favor of generics. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: You really need to provide the declaration for logic_bus here.

Comment: Have you considered simply leaving the port unconstrained without a generic,  and let the connection size the port? (As allowed since vhdl 1993  iirc)

Comment: @user16145658 I do not have a definition for `logic_bus`. This is my question : "how may I define logic_bus" to achieve syntactic sugar. Would you kindly develop "syntactic sugar is not a term of art" ? Isn't it a term a compiler/language theory which VHDL falls into ? Thank you kindly for your help.

Comment: The VHDL standard is an interoperability standard with normative references, otherwise internally defining and consistently using terminology. Your CS theory can only tell you what it should do not what the semantics say. An object declaration's subtype indication type mark (_type_ name) and constraint allows short hand 'syntactic sugar' - _subtype_ name. Neither of these support an indexed name  or a function call (an expression). The standard doesn't identify syntactic sugar as such requiring learning *the difference between type and subtype*.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want `logic_bus(x)` to be some kind function/alias/subtype to abstract away `std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0)`, working around constrained vector declaration.

VHDL have a quite small user base in terms of numbers. So much of what of the language you can use is highly tool dependent. Make sure you have read up on the supported features of vhdl-2008 for your development environment. As a main user of Xilinx UG901 is my go to for Vivado. Even though a feature is supported you might sometime be required to add an keep attribute to make it not be optimized away in synthesis.

Since a few years back Vivado have a quite full support for vhdl-2008

Unbounded arrays have been supported for even longer.
Generic package have just seen the light of day and seems to be a bit different in Mentor and Xilinx interpretation, but you can make it implement.
Generic types is a part of the language, but I have never got it to work the way I needed it to. *(I always try to keep to sl and slv in entity)*

As I'm not sure about your environment I can only answer for mine.

Full VHDL-2008 support is assumed

### Unconstrained slv

Working around constrained vector definition by avoiding it.

```vhdl
entity X is
    port(
        DataIn : in std_logic_vector;
        DataOut : out std_logic_vector
    );
end entity;

architecture X_arch of X is
    -- guiding DataSignal with to have a relationship with some signal is usally needed  
    signal DataSignal : std_logic_vector(DataIn'range);
begin
    assert DataIn'length = DataOut'length
        report "length missmatch of input and output data"
        severity ERROR;
    
    DataOut <= DataSignal;
    DataSignal <= DataIn;
end architecture;
```

Asserts will need to be enabled for synthesis, ether for the run or appended to the synthesis strategy. (see ug901, for Xilinx or check vendor docs)

Unconstrained vectors need to be constrained at the top level. Some times a bit flakey in multi layered component designs. Signals are usually a bit iffy about how they get inferred.

### Higher dimensional data can also be unconstrained

```vhdl
type slv_2d is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;

-- Constrain multiple dimensions at once 
-- (this might still be broken in GHDL, open issue last time i checked) 
-- synthesis/implementation in Vivado works
-- simulates in Modelsim/Questa works
signal test_signal : slv_2d(0 to 5)(7 downto 0);


-- constants can de inferred from assignment
constant test_signal : slv_2d := ("001", "010", "011", "100" );
```

`subtype` I usually think about as limiting a type further.

```vhdl
-- integer may be any value within -2147483648 to +2147483647.
-- I might have an issue or a design restriction to highlight
-- I usually don't use subtypes 
subtype my_range is integer range 0 to 255;

-- Will throw error if outside of range 0 to 255.
variable cnt : my_range := 0;
```

I really recommend reading ug901 "Supported VHDL-2008 Features" section of the latest release, even if you don't work with Xilinx. Dolus have a few really good writeups on vhdl-2008 that might strike your fancy and will talk about related features to what you are looking for.

Comment: *'m not really sure what you are going for with the functions.* There are no functions present in the OP's code. Vectors isn't a term of art in the VHDL standard. You appear to mean an unbounded array definition in a type declaration that would receive an array constraint in a subtype indication. ug901 is not authored by someone schooled in the art. Did you mean 'strike your fancy', an idiom found in dictionaries?

Comment: A little more explicitly demonstrating the lack of functions, the type mark logic_bus in the OP's code for port signal and  signal DataSignal declarations is either type name or a subtype name, neither of which can have a function call as a prefix.

Comment: Thanks @user16145658 for your comment, I've tried to update accordingly :) Great point.  You leave me a bit worried by the comment "ug901 is not authored by someone schooled in the art". Have a great Easter

Comment: You can describe VHDL expertise using the Journeyman system. A master demonstrates his art by implementing the language and maintain implementations error free. Journeymen work unsupervised and are conversant in the art (the standard). Apprentices require task direction and feedback and learn the art. Documentation writers are hard pressed as apprentices, their efforts not well supervised generally. Superimposing external terminology isn't useful in understanding the standard. It's a formal notation using terminology defined in the standard itself.

Comment: @Halfow Thank you very much for your proposal. It is a clever approach. Yet I have some issue with using constraints inference and was really hoping for an answer closer from your initial understanding of my question "[…] you want logic_bus(x) to be some kind function/alias/subtype to abstract away std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0)". I will update my question in accordance. Cordially.

Comment: Also for "will throw error" read "will throw error if tool defaults aren't set to turn errors off". *cough* Xilinx will you please fix your simulator?